# Resolving circular dependencies in a python/django application

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model that calls a file parser (to parse a file) and that file parser calls the model to save the object. Currently, the code looks something like this:

**models.py**

```
class Source(models.Model):
    ...

    def parse_file(self):
        from ingest.parser import FileParser
        ...
```

**ingest.py**

```
class FileParser()

    def save(self):
        from models import Source
        ...
```

This 'works' fine, however, doing the import within the save method adds about `0.25s` the first time I have to use it, as it's initializing the import. Is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: why not import at top of file, instead of inside method

Comment: @VaibhavVishal otherwise it would give me a circular import error.

Comment: Did you try to use `get_model` function where you can get model by a string name?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which solution did you end up preferring?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I used the "put it at the bottom" approach you suggested below. However, is there a standard practice for how to do that? For example, are you supposed to include a commented import at the top which says something like "Actual import at bottom of file to resolve circular dependencies", or what do your files usually look like this that implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a module is first loaded, a module object with an empty namespace is placed immediately into `sys.modules`. The namespace is filled in as the module code is executed. Any further references to the module just retrieve the reference in `sys.modues`, regardless of whether it is completely loaded or not. This yields two approaches to the problem.

**Method 1**

Since the imported names are not used outside methods, you only need to ensure that they exist by the time the methods are called, not when they are first created.

You can fix the import issue by placing the offending imports at the end of your respective files. That way, no matter which module gets loaded first, all the top level names in it will be initialized before the other module tries to access them:

**models.py**

```
class Source(models.Model):
    ...

    def parse_file(self):
        ...

from ingest.parser import FileParser
```

**ingest.py**

```
class FileParser()
    def save(self):
        ...

from models import Source
```

If `models.py` is loaded first, the line `from ingest.parser import FileParser` will trigger a load of `ingest.py`, but only after `Source` is defined in the module namespace. That means that `from models import Source` will be able to find the name. The same applies in the reverse order.

If you know which module will always be loaded first, then only one of the imports needs to be moved to the end of the file (the one in the file being loaded first).

**Method 2**

A simpler alternative might be to just import the modules, rather than trying to extract names from them. That would allow you to keep the imports at the top of your file, since an empty module object will be available to satisfy the circular import:

**models.py**

```
from ingest import parser

class Source(models.Model):
    ...

    def parse_file(self):
        # use parser.FileParser
        ...
```

**ingest.py**

```
import models

class FileParser()
    def save(self):
        # use models.Source
        ...
```

Comment: great answer. Thank you very much for your thoroughness.

Comment: You're very welcome. I've run into this issue enough times where I could swear your question was a duplicate, but I can't seem to find an exact enough match.